# Efficiently find common ancestor in postgresql directed acyclic graph

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

Given a directed acyclic graph shaped like this:

```
  "Branch A"               "Branch B"

branch-a-head-id        branch-b-head-id           ---
       |                        |                   ^
     id-Z                     id-C                  |
       |                        |                   |
     id-Y                     id-B                  |
       |                        |               "Branch A"
     id-X                     id-A                 and
       |                        |               "Branch B"
branch-a-first-id       branch-b-first-id           |
       |                        |                   |
        \                      /                    |
         \                    /                     |
          \                  /                      v
           common-ancestor-id                      ---
                   |                                ^
                 id-2                               |
                   |                         "Common Segment"
                 id-1                               |
                   |                                v
               initial-id                          ---
```

And modeled in a PostgreSQL table structure like:

```
select * from graphtable;
   id              |     parent
-------------------+--------------
initial-id         | (NULL)
id-1               | initial-id
id-2               | id-1
common-ancestor-id | id-2
branch-a-first-id  | common-ancestor-id
id-X               | branch-a-first-id
id-Y               | id-X
id-Z               | id-Y
branch-a-head-id   | id-Z
branch-b-first-id  | common-ancestor-id
id-A               | branch-b-first-id
id-B               | id-A
id-C               | id-B
branch-b-head-id   | id-C
```

I need a query to find the common ancestor between "Branch A" and "Branch B". Here is a query that works *but is inefficient*:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE linked_list(id, parent) AS (
    SELECT id, parent
    FROM graphtable
    WHERE id = 'branch-a-head-id' OR id = 'branch-b-head-id'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT g.id, g.parent
    FROM graphtable g
    INNER JOIN linked_list ll ON ll.parent = g.id
)
SELECT string_agg(id, ',') AS ids, parent
FROM linked_list
GROUP BY parent HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1;
```

Which for the above structure returns:

```
                 ids                 |       parent       
-------------------------------------+--------------------
 branch-a-first-id,branch-b-first-id | common-ancestor-id
```

This is inefficient because it always runs through all rows until it finds one with a NULL parent. That means that if you have a structure where "Branch A" and "Branch B" are both small (e.g. 100 rows each) but the "Common Segment" is large (millions of rows) it will iterate over millions of rows instead of hundreds.

Here's a benchmark with 100 nodes in "Branch A" and 100 nodes in "Branch B" and variable number of "Common Segment" nodes:

| # Common Segment nodes | Query time (seconds) |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | 0.011 |
| 32 | 0.008 |
| 64 | 0.011 |
| 128 | 0.014 |
| 256 | 0.026 |
| 512 | 0.058 |
| 1024 | 0.146 |
| 2048 | 0.44 |
| 4096 | 0.028 |
| 8192 | 0.049 |
| 16384 | 0.104 |
| 32768 | 0.209 |
| 65536 | 0.423 |
| 131072 | 0.859 |
| 262144 | 1.781 |
| 524288 | 3.914 |

**The question: how to make this query efficient?** This appears to be O(C) where C is the number of Common Segment nodes. I hope to be able to achieve O(A+B) where A and B are number of Branch A and Branch B nodes. In other words, complexity should be independent of C.

My examples above both have A and B with the same number of nodes. That is not necessarily the case. I'm not certain at this time what the actual range of segment lengths may be, but my estimates are:

- A and B: 10s to 1000s
- Common: 1000s to hundred-thousands

I'm specifically interested in Postgres. Thanks!

Comment: Show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query when run with enough nodes that performance is a problem.

Comment: Try reducing the search space. Any node that has a single child node cannot be the nearest common ancestor to any other pair of nodes. Also, you didn't specify whether or not a node could have more than one parent. On a stylistic note, although trees in nature grow from the bottom up, the general convention in computer science is to branch downward. There is no O(1) solution to this search problem. What do you mean  by "100 nodes per branch and only varying number of common nodes?" Please update the post with the table DDL and code to populate the tables to reproduce your tests cases.

Comment: @JohnH I have two branches in the diagram at the top, one with the head node `branch-a-head-id` the other with head `branch-b-head-id`. So "A" and "B", respectively. Sorry that wasn't clearer. I'm saying imagine a larger graph with 100 nodes in each of those independent branches, and then a "common" portion of the graph that both A and B belong to (i.e. nodes id-1 and id-2) which I've varied from 16 to 500k in my table.  Concur with the recommendation of reducing search space. I'm working on a solution with tracking depth and doing something like `WHERE depth < 10000`.

Comment: I would write a database function for that.

Comment: Recursion performance suffers as depth increases.  That is just how it is.  Have you considered using ltree so that each row contains its path to the root?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html  The ltree extension includes an `lca(<ltree>, <ltree>)` function that makes your query a no-brainer.

Comment: @MikeOrganek I'm not familiar with ltree but in reading the docs you linked it seems similar to cycle detection like `CYCLE id SET is_cycle USING path` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html. If so, I'm seeing the query times and the RAM usage blow up very quickly. I'm assuming this is because a `path` column is being added for each row, and when you're iterating over 10s of thousands of rows that makes this column very large.

Comment: Your ASCII art makes it look like the tree is symmetric. I.e., the common ancestor is the same number of nodes away. Is that so?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter no not necessarily. Sorry for the confusing image.

Comment: What are the basic cardinalities? What is the avg / max length of each path? Is it just as likely that one leg has 1000 nodes and the other just 5 as both being similar length? Are shorter paths more likely in general? Any meta information can help to speed it up (dramatically).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I edited the question. As stated in the question, I'm not certain exactly, but I think A and B may be in the 10s to 1000s range and the Common Segment may be in the 1000s to hundred thousands.

Answer (score 2):

Even though PL/pgSQL is quite slow compared to SQL, I still recommend writing a database function. The algorithm is procedural, so that is a natural choice. And that way it is easy to avoid fetching *all* the ancestors of either argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION first_common_ancestor(a text, b text) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$DECLARE
   iter integer := 1;
   a_ancestors text[] := ARRAY[a];
   b_ancestors text[] := ARRAY[b];
   a_next text;
   b_next text;
   a_done boolean := FALSE;
   b_done boolean := FALSE;
BEGIN
   WHILE NOT a_done AND NOT b_done LOOP
      /* test if we have found a common ancestor */
      IF ARRAY[a_ancestors[iter]] && b_ancestors THEN
         RETURN a_ancestors[iter];
      END IF;
      IF ARRAY[b_ancestors[iter]] && a_ancestors THEN
         RETURN b_ancestors[iter];
      END IF;

      /* get the next ancestors */
      SELECT parent INTO a_next
      FROM graphtable
      WHERE id = a_ancestors[iter];

      IF FOUND THEN
         a_ancestors := a_ancestors || a_next;
      ELSE
         a_done := TRUE;
      END IF;

      SELECT parent INTO b_next
      FROM graphtable
      WHERE id = b_ancestors[iter];

      IF FOUND THEN
         b_ancestors := b_ancestors || b_next;
      ELSE
         b_done := TRUE;
      END IF;

      iter := iter + 1;
   END LOOP;

   /* no common ancestor */
   RETURN NULL;
END;$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It seems more efficient in some scenarios. I'll investigate more tomorrow and report back.

Answer (score 1):

I see four possible solutions:

1. The original query from the question
2. Limiting query depth within the CTE
3. Preventing cycles within the CTE
4. Using PL/pgSQL (per suggestion in [Laurenz Albe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77085825/2782380))

Below are the four queries.

#### Original

This is a re-posting of the original query from the question to make it easier to see the changes in the following two queries.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE linked_list(id, parent) AS (
    SELECT id, parent
    FROM graphtable
    WHERE id = 'branch-a-head-id' OR id = 'branch-b-head-id'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT g.id, g.parent
    FROM graphtable g
    INNER JOIN linked_list ll ON ll.parent = g.id
)
SELECT string_agg(id, ',') AS ids, parent
FROM linked_list
GROUP BY parent HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1;
```

#### Limiting query depth within the CTE

See line comments for changes from Original.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE linked_list(id, parent, depth) AS (    -- line changed
    SELECT id, parent, 0                              -- line changed
    FROM graphtable
    WHERE id = $1 OR id = $2
  UNION ALL
    SELECT g.id, g.parent, ll.depth + 1
    FROM graphtable g
    INNER JOIN linked_list ll ON ll.parent = g.id
    WHERE depth < 10000                               -- line added
)
SELECT string_agg(id, ',') AS ids, parent
FROM linked_list
GROUP BY parent HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1;
```

#### Preventing cycles

See line comments for changes from Original.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE linked_list(id, parent) AS (
    SELECT id, parent
    FROM graphtable
    WHERE id = 'branch-a-head-id' OR id = 'branch-b-head-id'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT g.id, g.parent
    FROM graphtable g
    INNER JOIN linked_list ll ON ll.parent = g.id
)
CYCLE id SET is_cycle USING path                       -- line added
SELECT string_agg(id, ',') AS ids, parent
FROM linked_list
GROUP BY parent HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1;
```

#### PL/pgSQL

See [Laurenz Albe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77085825/2782380). In my testing I ran:

```sql
SELECT first_common_ancestor('branch-a-head-id', 'branch-b-head-id') AS parent
```

#### Comparison of queries with 100 nodes in A and B and variable Common Segment nodes

The table below shows a series of test results

| # Common Nodes | Original query (sec) | Limited depth (sec) | Prevent cycles (sec) | PL/pgSQL (sec) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 0.023 | 0.014 | 0.02 | 0.012 |
| 32 | 0.023 | 0.009 | 0.014 | 0.007 |
| 64 | 0.022 | 0.012 | 0.018 | 0.008 |
| 128 | 0.024 | 0.016 | 0.028 | 0.009 |
| 256 | 0.027 | 0.028 | 0.064 | 0.008 |
| 512 | 0.030 | 0.055 | 0.185 | 0.008 |
| 1024 | 0.033 | 0.142 | 0.596 | 0.007 |
| 2048 | 0.047 | 0.016 | 1.922 | 0.008 |
| 4096 | 0.063 | 0.027 | 8.369 | 0.008 |
| 8192 | 0.098 | 0.056 | 16.499 | 0.008 |
| 16384 | 0.205 | 0.061 | 104.991 | 0.010 |
| 32768 | 0.361 | 0.069 | Too slow to test | 0.008 |
| 65536 | 0.681 | 0.063 | Too slow to test | 0.007 |
| 131072 | 1.353 | 0.064 | Too slow to test | 0.009 |
| 262144 | 2.934 | 0.064 | Too slow to test | 0.009 |
| 524288 | 5.954 | 0.099 | Too slow to test | 0.008 |
| 1048576 | 12.83 | 0.075 | Too slow to test | 0.010 |
| 2097152 | 30.904 | 0.079 | Too slow to test | 0.010 |

Results:

- Original = O(C) as stated in the question
- Limited depth = O(1) for this test holding A and B constant, likely O(A + B)
- Preventing cycles = Blows up fast, probably O(C^2) or worse. This is likely because cycle detection adds a `path` column holding every id in the current row's ancestry, which (a) dramatically increases memory requirements and (b) requires that each row do a search within `path` (which is itself an O(C) operation)
- PL/pgSQL = O(1) for this test holding A and B constant, likely O(A + B)

In this test, PL/pgSQL and Limited Depth are both big improvements, with PL/pgSQL being about an order of magnitude faster.

#### Comparison of queries with 10000 nodes in A and B and variable Common Segment nodes

This is the same test as above but with 10000 nodes in A and B each instead of 100. Original and Cycle Detection weren't tested.

| # Common Nodes | Limit Depth (sec) | PL/pgSQL (sec) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 0.085 | 1.552 |
| 32 | 0.076 | 1.612 |
| 64 | 0.085 | 1.538 |
| 128 | 0.078 | 1.396 |
| 256 | 0.080 | 1.399 |
| 512 | 0.080 | 1.392 |
| 1024 | 0.080 | 1.394 |
| 2048 | 0.100 | 1.480 |
| 4096 | 0.084 | 1.406 |
| 8192 | 0.078 | 1.423 |
| 16384 | 0.082 | 1.417 |
| 32768 | 0.093 | 1.412 |
| 65536 | 0.073 | 1.416 |
| 131072 | 0.073 | 1.421 |
| 262144 | 0.075 | 1.393 |
| 524288 | 0.081 | 1.401 |
| 1048576 | 0.084 | 1.473 |
| 2097152 | 0.098 | 1.465 |

Results: Both still constant with respect to C, but now Limited Depth is at least an order of magnitude faster than PL/pgSQL

#### Conclusion

- If you know that A and B are in the 100s range, PL/pgSQL is faster
- If you know that A and B are in the 10s of thousands range, Limited Depth is faster
- If unsure, Limited Depth is probably safer since PL/pgSQL query duration seems to increase faster. This assumes you can set a reasonable depth limit, since if your depth limit is less than the length of A or B then you'll never find the common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution with PL/pgSQL.

Only makes sense for deep roots - many nodes to the common ancestor. The point being to avoid executing a single-row `SELECT` and array concatenation for every single element. Instead, collect an (adjustable) number of nodes and concatenate that once - while the search continues. With a shortcut for the other leg, after one leg ends.

Hard to say where the additional overhead starts to pay off. Test with different data sets and different batch sizes (`_batch_size`). I set the default at 100. It's increased dynamically with every iteration in the loop to cover both short and long paths.

Auxiliary function to dig up a given number of steps:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_roots(_a text, _b_roots text[], _batch_size int)
  RETURNS text[]
  LANGUAGE sql STABLE STRICT
BEGIN ATOMIC
WITH RECURSIVE roots AS (
   SELECT g.parent AS node
   FROM   graphtable g
   WHERE  g.id = _a

   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT g.parent FROM graphtable g WHERE g.id = r.node)
   FROM   roots r   
   WHERE  r.node <> ALL(_b_roots)
   )
SELECT ARRAY(TABLE roots LIMIT _batch_size);
END;
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/300512/3684)

It takes the node to be advanced, and the array of nodes from the other side. The last element is `null` if the root node has been reached.
The functions stops at the first match, so (only) the last element can be a match.

Main function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_common_root(_a text, _b text, _batch_size int = 100)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE AS
$func$
DECLARE
   a_roots  text[] := ARRAY[_a];
   b_roots  text[] := ARRAY[_b];
   a_step   text[];
   b_step   text[];
   last_a   text := _a;
   last_b   text := _b;
BEGIN
   -- corner case
   IF _a = _b THEN
      RETURN _a;
   END IF;

   LOOP
      -- get the next _batch_size nodes for a
      IF last_a IS NOT NULL THEN
         a_step := f_roots(last_a, b_roots, _batch_size);
         last_a := a_step[array_upper(a_step, 1)];

         IF last_a IS NULL THEN
            -- trim last null!
            a_roots := a_roots || a_step[1:array_upper(a_step, 1)-1];
         ELSIF last_a = ANY(b_roots) THEN
            RETURN last_a;
         ELSE
            a_roots := a_roots || a_step;
         END IF;
      END IF;

      -- shortcut to finish other side (no more array concatenation needed)
      IF last_a IS NULL THEN
         LOOP
            SELECT INTO last_b  g.parent
            FROM   graphtable g
            WHERE  g.id = last_b;
            
            IF NOT FOUND THEN
               RETURN null;
            ELSIF last_b = ANY(a_roots) THEN
               RETURN last_b;
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
      END IF;


      -- EXACTLY symmetrical for b
      IF last_b IS NOT NULL THEN
         b_step := f_roots(last_b, a_roots, _batch_size);
         last_b := b_step[array_upper(b_step, 1)];

         IF last_b IS NULL THEN
            b_roots := b_roots || b_step[1:array_upper(b_step, 1)-1];
         ELSIF last_b = ANY(a_roots) THEN
            RETURN last_b;
         ELSE
            b_roots := b_roots || b_step;
         END IF;
      END IF;      
      
      IF last_b IS NULL THEN
         LOOP
            SELECT INTO last_a  g.parent
            FROM   graphtable g
            WHERE  g.id = last_a;
            
            IF NOT FOUND THEN
               RETURN null;
            ELSIF last_a = ANY(b_roots) THEN
               RETURN last_a;
            END IF;
         END LOOP;
      END IF;

      -- grow batch_size dynamically
      _batch_size := (_batch_size * 1.5)::int;
   END LOOP;   
END
$func$;
```

Call (with optional custom `_batch_size`):

```
SELECT f_common_root('branch-a-head-id', 'branch-b-head-id');

SELECT f_common_root('branch-a-head-id', 'branch-b-head-id', 500);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XAiDV7al)